# TCP socket connection over cellular data or internet

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

I have made a java project on which communication is build between Server and Client using TCP sockets.The client end has Server's IP address and common ports.

Server:

```
    ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(80);
    int id=1;
    while(true)
    {
        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        WorkerThread wt = new WorkerThread(connectionSocket, id);
        Thread t = new Thread(wt);
        t.start();
        workerThreadCount++;
        System.out.println("Client [" + id + "] is now connected. No. of worker threads = " + workerThreadCount);
        id++;
    }
```

Client end:

```
        Socket skt = new Socket("103.94.135.201", 80);
        outToServer = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);
        inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));
```

It all works when both ends are in same WiFi.But it frustratingly fails when client end is using cellular data.

Any solution?

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve]? A short self-contained code snippet that can reproduce the error? An error message or desired vs. actual output would also be useful.

Comment: TCP sockets work the same way regardless of what kind of networks are being used. More likely, this is going to end up being a routing issue between the server's network and the client's network, not a coding issue. Does the server's network have a public IP that the client is allowed to connect to, not blocked by the server's ISP? Does the server's network router have port forwarding enabled so it can forward the client's traffic to the server machine?

Comment: One more possibility:  It might be that the client's cell-interface is being provided an IPv6 address (but not an IPv4 address), in which case both the client and the server would need to use IPv6 in order to communicate.

Comment: UPD: I added the code fractions.Please review.